# What is the value of a dialog constant DS_RECURSE?

Tags: winapi

What is the value of a dialog constant DS_RECURSE (link to the official MS documentation required, historical information is welcome) ?
Thanks for attention.

Comment: Odd that this is now the top result on Google for `DS_RECURSE`...

Comment: Why are you asking about the value of a constant about which the documentation says "Don't use this"? It's like somebody saying "Do not call the phone number 555-Z5Z5" and you ask "How do I dial a Z?" Why do you care how to dial a Z? The person told you not to do it!

Comment: @Raymond "It's like somebody saying "Do not call the phone number 555-Z5Z5" and you ask "How do I dial a Z?"
Not so: somebody many many years saying "Do not call the phone number 555-Z5Z5", "Do not call the phone number 555-Z5Z5", "Do not call the phone number 555-Z5Z5".
Of course, this will draw attention ...

"Why do you care how to dial a Z? The person told you not to do it!".
Not so: i don't care how to dial a Z, i care about the person told me Z.

Comment: Then don't ask "How do I dial a Z?" Ask "Why are you telling me to do something that's impossible?" Right now, you're asking, "How do I dial a Z?"

Comment: @RaymondChen what if the user wants to know how to use the feature (dialing Z's) that they just discovered exists?

Comment: @immibis The only documentation about Z says "Don't do it." There is no documentation that says what happens when you dial a Z, so why would you want to do something where the consequences are undefined?

Answer (score 9):

`DS_RECURSE` doesn't exist. It was a flag in a prerelease version of Windows 95 that was removed before RTM. All the docs that refer to it talk about "Don't use it", which is now very easy to do because you can't use something that doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the historical information. I suspected Win31. You wrote: "Why are you asking about the value of a constant about which the documentation says "Don't use this"? 
Is very simple: because I'm interested. May now only you can tell: either DS_RECURSE (at a time when it existed) took the last free bit in low word (0x00004000), or a mixture of bits like DS_SHELLFONT...
Or is it really that big a secret? :)

Comment: The answer to this question is not practical. StackOverflow is for practical programming problems, not for satisfying curiosity about programming history.

Comment: Then the most appropriate place to respond to DS_RECURSE - TheOldNewThing! Are you agree ? :)

Comment: @kero: apparently Raymond did agree: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/09/24/10560089.aspx

Comment: @John Zwinck, I see :) Btw, the numerical value I got last year yet (http://rsdn.ru/forum/winapi/5080414.1).

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925154.aspx

```
The following styles are not supported for the **style** member of the DLGTEMPLATE structure: 

...
DS_RECURSE
    Not required. Any child dialog box is automatically considered to be a recursive dialog box.
```

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct {
  DWORD style; 
  DWORD dwExtendedStyle; 
  WORD cdit; 
  short x; 
  short y; 
  short cx; 
  short cy; 
} DLGTEMPLATE;
```

As you see, style is DWORD so is the value of DS_RECURSE a DWORD as well.
Let it be 0 because not required.

BTW: for what reason do you need it?