# Close the running Notepad from my application in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to close all the running instances of Notepad through my application. 
I got the window handle `using`

> FindWindow() API.

I got the handle of Window.

> CloseWindow() API

is minimizing the notepad but I want to close all the instances of Notepad.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17169558/501196

Answer (score -1):

By using `FindWindow()` you will get `HWND`

Use that `HWND` to get `pid` i.e process id.

```
HWND hWnd;  // using findwindow you will get hWnd
DWORD pid;
TCHAR tcInput [MAX_PATH];
CString strName;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&pid);
//::GetWindowText(hWnd,tcInput,MAX_PATH);
//strName = (CString)tcInput;
//if(strName.MakeLower().Find( _T("untitle"))!=-1)   //you can check windows title here
    KillProcess(pid);  // kill the process
```

Comment: Lots of commented out (and completely unrelated) code, followed by some fantasy API call. Sorry, -1 for sloppiness alone.